# Colon in custom request headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

How can I send HTTP headers with `:` to another server (not mine)? Is it possible?

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'example.net',
    path: '/',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        ':custom': 'Custom Header Demo works'
    }
};

callback = function (response) {
    var str = ''
    response.on('data', (chunk) => str += chunk);
    response.on('end', () => console.log(str));
}

var req = http.request(options, callback);
req.write("foo=bar");
req.end();
```

Here is what I get:

`TypeError: Header name must be a valid HTTP Token [":custom"]`

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you are trying to do.. ":custom" is not a valid HTTP header...

Comment: Remote server accept headers only with colon. Sorry, my english so poor

Comment: I guess you would have to [patch `lib/_http_outgoing.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/cfc8422a68c92808a4a2aee374623bebc768522a/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L495) for this. Not really advisable, as that `:custom` header really isn't RFC-compliant as @Badacadabra pointed out. Get in touch with the owner of that server and have him sort this out.

Comment: @DaSourcerer Ok, thank you, it helps